# Nuget package for .netcore TestScheduler

Tags: c#, .net, rx.net

This is rather silly but I can't seem to find the .net rx nuget package that contains the TestScheduler

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a software library are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TestScheduler` is in the [Microsoft.Reactive.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Reactive.Testing/) nuget package.

Comment: Totally makes sens, the rest of the library is in `System.Reactive.*`